# Qt ignore click when dismissing popup on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have an issue with Qt where the behavior on Windows is different than Mac or Linux. I discovered the issue on PySide2 but was able to reproduce it in a minimal C++ application as well (see below).

When I dismiss a Popup widget by clicking outside the click is ignored by the rest of the application. This is the desired behavior and is the way it works on Linux and Mac. However in Windows this click is registered by the widget that was clicked which in my application leads to unwanted user input on the underlying widgets.

Is there a way to will prevent the dismissal click from being passed on in Windows? I am fine with having platform dependent code for this issue.

The behavior can be reproduced with this example. When the popup is open and `testButton` is clicked the `onTestButton` method will be executed.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
  this->setFixedHeight(600);
  this->setFixedWidth(800);

  QWidget* w = new QWidget();

  QDialog* popUp = new QDialog();
  popUp->setFixedHeight(200);
  popUp->setFixedWidth(200);
  popUp->setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  popUp->setModal(true);
  popUp->setVisible(false);

  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
  w->setLayout(layout);

  QPushButton* openButton = new QPushButton("open popup");
  // same behavior whether using QDialog::show or QDialog::exec
  connect(openButton, &QPushButton::clicked, popUp, &QDialog::show);
  QPushButton* testButton = new QPushButton("catch mouse");
  connect(testButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onTestButton);

  layout->addWidget(openButton);
  layout->addWidget(testButton);
  this->layout()->addWidget(w);
}

void MainWindow::onTestButton()
{
  qDebug() << "caught mouse";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but do you mean you have modality issues?
Please check `QDialog::setModal(bool modal)`

Comment: I added (see code) this but the dismissing mouse click is still registered by the other widgets.

Comment: When you use `QDialog` you don't need the flag `Qt::Popup`. Also, why do you use `popUp->setVisible(false);` ?

Answer (score 0):

QWidget is just a widget, if you want it to "hold" focus, then use QDialog instead.
Also it changes the "logic" if u use it as QDialog.show or QDialog.exec.
Can you try with QDialog?

Comment: Thanks, I did change it to a QDialog (as shown in the question now) and tested both `QDialog::show` and `QDialog::exec`. In both cases the dismissing mouse click is still passed to the other widgets.

Comment: @HerrvonWurst remove Qt::Popup and popUp->setModal(true); and popUp->setVisible(false);. Dialog is not visible untill you ask to show/exec it.
All you really need is auto dialog  = new QDialog(); dialog->exec();

Answer (score -1):

`QDialog::setModal(bool)` should set the dialog to modal, thus prohibiting clicking into the mainwindow.

Your windowflag `Qt::Popup` blocked modality. If you want to use that approach and create `Qwidget` as a modal dialog (`Qt::Dialog`), it should be launched from another window, or have a parent and used with the `QWidget::windowModality` property.

Tested:

```
 auto w = new QWidget;

 QDialog* popUp = new QDialog;
 popUp->setFixedHeight(200);
 popUp->setFixedWidth(200);
 popUp->setWindowFlags( Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
 popUp->setModal(true);

 QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
 w->setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: I want to be able to dismiss / close the dialog by clicking outside of the dialog into the mainwindow (modal dialogs can not do this). However I do not want the click to be registered as an event by the mainwindows widgets. This is the way it works for my example on the other platforms. The question is if there is a way to have the same behavior in Windows.

Comment: For that you need to implement your own custom dialog and reimplement the `focusOutEvent`., where you close the dialog... Also, edit your code snippet because you mixed up Qwidget with QDialog there, and made typos so it's not compilable.

Comment: Can you explain how you would use the focus out event to eat that mouse click?

Comment: When you click outside of the dialog, you lose the focus from that widget, therefore the `focusOutEvent` is triggered there:
1. create your custom dialog
2. reimplement `focusOutEvent`
3. call `close()`

If you only want to achieve that the it closes ONLY if you clicked inside the main widget, you need to do the other way around, via  main widget's `focusInEvent`